# Webview Push Notifications for Blogger

Tags: android, webview, push-notification, blogger

I was thinking of developing an android webview application for my blog and I would want my subscribers to get notifies through push notification whenever I post a new post in y blog.

First off, is this possible?
and if Yes kindly help me to understand how.

I am looking forward to your answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact i did the same for my blog on wordpress.

Checkout [THIS link](http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/2015/07/profesional-android-webview-application.html), which will show you how to create android app for your blog. This includes complete tutorial with souce code for splash screen, Sharing feature and android webview.

Note : If you don't know how to code, still you can build android app for your blog without any extra efforts. For that you can use :

- Appsgeyser
- Appypie

There are many other options available you can google it.

For PUSH Notification, i suggest you to use [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/signup). Basically Parse is based on GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). To use parse in your app you need to sign up with parse. After successful sign up you will have client keys and credentials to use parse. Parse will provide a step by step code you need to just paste it in appropriate files. That's it you are done.