# How to get a notification when i update on blogger?

Tags: webview, push-notification, notifications, blogger

i use a WebView on my application, and i want to get a notification when i update a post on blogger, what class such i use ?

i have an application that connected to my blogger

```
WebView a = new WebView()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview Push Notifications for Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049498/webview-push-notifications-for-blogger)

Comment: i didn't find my answer there